# Problems with implementing QRCodeReader (ZXing)

Tags: c++, objective-c, qr-code, zxing

So I've followed the steps mentioned here: http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/iphone/README

And I made sure everything is alright but yet my QRCodeReader isn't being recognized in myVC.mm file.

This is what's the situation: 
The project is put into my own project as described in the link.
I've imported the `#import "ZXingWidgetController.h"` in the header file and it is being recognized.
I've imported the `#import "QRCodeReader.h"` in the implementation file (.mm)
Then I alloced them both in a targetmethod of some button like this:

```
    ZXingWidgetController *widController = [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:self showCancel:YES OneDMode:NO];
    widController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"qr_code_initialising_bg.png"]];
    QRCodeReader* qrcodeReader = [[QRCodeReader alloc] init];
    NSSet *readers = [[NSSet alloc ] initWithObjects:qrcodeReader,nil];
    [qrcodeReader release];
    widController.readers = readers;
    [readers release];
    [self presentModalViewController:widController animated:YES];
```

Now it tells me that this is the problem:

```
        QRCodeReader* qrcodeReader = [[QRCodeReader alloc] init];
    NSSet *readers = [[NSSet alloc ] initWithObjects:qrcodeReader,nil];
    [qrcodeReader release];
```

It says: `Use of undeclared identifier 'QRCodeReader'`

- Why does it not see my import of the QRCodeReader in the seem .mm
  file?
- What did I forget that is not in the description that I used?
- And most important, how do I fix this to recognize the QRCodeReader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The straight C++ code (not Objective C++) uses C++ namespaces.

You need to either say `zxing::qrcode::QRCodeReader` or use `using` statements like

```
  using namespace zxing;
  using namespace zxing::qrcode;
```

**Update**:

The code above does bring in the C++ class but there's actually a widget class of the same name which I forgot about. It is an Objective C class that wraps the C++ class and is what you want. Instead of the code above, just `#import "QRCodeReader.h"` ... which you said you did. I expect the two files of the same name are colliding. Did you set the "recursive" option when including the cpp files? The README says "don't need to" but should probably say "must not". That could cause the cpp file to be included and not the widget version.

Comment: Alright I've tried that but and it doesn't bug, which is good. How do I add this c++ code to an NSSet since widController.readers needs to be set with an NSSet.

Comment: That's a different question and probably shouldn't be posted as a comment. You'll have trouble adding C++ objects to Objective C collections because C++ objects are not NSObjects. There are a set of Objective C wrappers for some of the zxing types in the zxing objc directory. These would allow you to mix more easily with Objective C but there's really no documentation for the objc classes. You'll have to read the code. (Follow ups should probably be on the zxing google group.)

Comment: Hmm it does seem to compile when I simply cast it to (id) when I set it in the NSSet and then add it to widController.readers

Could you comfirm this is good practise?

Comment: I will post it as another question then. Thanks for the start^^

Comment: The update you posted puts me back into the initial problem, which is that he won't recognize the QRCodeReader class even tho I imported it where it belongs.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. My bad. Did you get the last update, to make sure you're not recursively including the cpp headers?

Comment: I set all the options to recursive. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: It can be. Recursive includes is not typical, at least not in the C/C++ world. People use directories to avoid file name collisions like I think you're seeing. It's possible it's more common in Objective C/Apple code but I never turn it on and never notice any issues.

Comment: Restarted and cleaned project. It's being recognized and compiles nicely. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem at the end the solution was kind of easy.

I put the .mm file with "Location" -> "Relative to Project".

Hope this help